# Chrome Extension Javascript not triggering action

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My buddy and I are creating our first chrome extension as a class project, but can't seem to get over this hump. After clicking the extension icon in the top right, we have a dropdown menu with a button and upon clicking, it should trigger a javascript function. Starting at the top, we created a dummy button with a test function which should trigger a console.log, yet no matter what we do nothing shows up in the console (or the inspect popup console).

**JS + HTML :**

```js
document.getElementById("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var btnStart = document.getElementById('startSc');
    btnStart.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("hi");
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>First Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="TBStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Go Chrome!</h1>
    <a href="#" id="startSc">Start</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**Manifest :**

```html
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) doesn't work that way.

I believe what your looking for is this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var btnStart = document.getElementById('startSc');
    btnStart.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("hi");
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>First Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="TBStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Go Chrome!</h1>
    <a href="#" id="startSc">Start</a>
</body>

</html>
```